# PHP - Add multiple items by index to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I have this array called $all_cats which outputs the following

```
Array(
    [0] => WP_Term Object(
        [term_id] => 386
        [name] => Ales
        [slug] => ales
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 386
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 384
        [count] => 10
        [filter] => raw
    )
    [1] => WP_Term Object(
        [term_id] => 385
        [name] => Beers
        [slug] => beers
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 385
        [taxonomy] => product_cat
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 384
        [count] => 10
        [filter] => raw
     )
)
```

I'm trying to add the "term_id" and "name" to an indexed multidimensional array so i can output the following -

Example A

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_cats] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 385,
                    [name] => "Beers"
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_cats] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 386,
                    [name] => "Ales"
                )

        )
)
```

I've tried the following but cant seem to add each item to the same key. How can i add each term_id & name so it outputs like example A?

```
$full_cats = array();

foreach ($all_cats as $cat_term) {

    $parent_termID = $cat_term->term_id;
    $parent_title = $cat_term->name;

    // this doesnt work
    $full_cats[]['parent_cats']['id'] = $parent_termID;
    $full_cats[]['parent_cats']['name'] = $parent_title;

    // this doesnt work
    array_push($full_cats[]['parent_cats']['id'],$parent_termID);
    array_push($full_cats[]['parent_cats']['name'],$parent_title);

}
```

How can i add each term_id & name so it outputs like example A?

Comment: Every time you start with `$full_cats[]... = something`, those `[]` will create a new entry on that level. But you don't want two new entries, you want only one, that holds both term id and name. So stick those into an array first, and then assign that to `$full_cats[]['parent_cats']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$full_cats = array();

foreach ($all_cats as $cat_term) {
    $parent_termID = $cat_term->term_id;
    $parent_title = $cat_term->name;

    // this doesnt work
    $full_cats[]=array(
                      "parent_cats"=>array(
                                       "id"   => $parent_termID,
                                       "name" => $parent_title
                      )
                  );
}
```

**The above code should work**

- You need to learn the structure of multi and assoc array

Answer (score 0):

```
$full_cats = array();
$indx = 0;

foreach ($all_cats as $cat_term) {

  $parent_termID = $cat_term->term_id;
  $parent_title = $cat_term->name;

  // this doesnt work
  $full_cats[$indx]['parent_cats']['id'] = $parent_termID;
  $full_cats[$indx]['parent_cats']['name'] = $parent_title;
  $indx++;

  // this doesnt work
  // array_push($full_cats[]['parent_cats']['id'],$parent_termID);
  // array_push($full_cats[]['parent_cats']['name'],$parent_title);

}
```